# Eclipse: how to execute an expression multiple while debugging without suspending the thread

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to test the render of my app when changing some values in a for loop.
For that reason I'm using  a break point in the loop and I defined a condition that contains an expression to be executed with every value, however I'm obliged to click on the F8 button to continue the execution.
 so I wonder If there is a way to run the expression without suspending the thread.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isnt that the actual use of debugging? To see the execution step by step

Comment: yeah, you are right, but in my case the render I will see it in a generated document, that's why I need to modify some value at *runtime* and the see the result on the generated doc

Comment: the document is an actual file? if so, you have to write the file before viewing it

Comment: Have you tried the [_Debug Shell_](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-debug_shell_view.htm) view?

Comment: Return true in your condition?

Comment: @nitind, that's what I'm doing, but I'm obliged to push the F8, because the thread is suspended whenever the condition return true.

Comment: @howlger, yeah the debug Shell works, but I was wondering if there is a better way, because in my case, I need to wait until all data are processed ( about 37*4 iteration ) and then create almost the same loop to override the data.

Comment: Maybe return false, then. You want it evaluated, you just *don't* want to stop.

Comment: in this case I think that it will be evaluated only once ??